# Test kitchen keeps waiting for ssh after creating instance for kitchen google

Tags: google-compute-engine, test-kitchen

The username is setup properly in the metadata and able to login to the box using the key.

But for some reason once the kitchen completes the instance creation, it keeps waiting for ssh and never is able to login.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem popped out when executed the kitchen create command in debug mode. The key used was different than my id_rsa which is default.

Hence had to make sure my ssh-agent was running and that they key was added to it.

Once the key was added to the ssh-agent, it logged right in.

Comment: Great to hear that you’ve solved your issue! Can you please [accept your own answer](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/accept-your-own-answers/) so that this question is marked as closed? Thanks!